# Does the local keyword on methods imply automatic storage?

Tags: system-verilog

What storage policy will variables declared in a `local function` inside a class have, static or automatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "storage policy" is the *lifetime*. It will always be automatic. Section 8.6 of IEEE 1800-2012 states

> The lifetime of methods declared as part of a class type shall be automatic. It shall be illegal to declare a
>   class method with a static lifetime.

You can declare a class method as being `static`, but in that context it means something entirely different. Section 8.10 states:

> A static method is different from a task with static lifetime. The former refers to the lifetime of the method
>   within the class, while the latter refers to the lifetime of the arguments and variables within the task.

So, a static method can be called even if no objects of that class exist.

Answer (score 0):

The `local` or `protected` attribute of a class member has no effect on the storage policy. It only affects the visibility of the identifier used to access the members.

That being said, the storage policy of a class member *also* affects the visibility of that identifier. So both features have the ability to restrict access, but for different reasons.

For example, you can never access an automatic variable from outside the scope of where it was declared. It does not matter if that scope is a class method, or a simple task. And it does not matter what the default lifetime of that scope was.

Conversely, if you declare a static variable in a scope, you might be able to access that variable from outside that scope, but you need to consider all the other visibility rules.